# Features can export everything?

Tags: theming

Built all blocks, menu, taxonomies, view etc in Drupal CMS on localhost machine, but I need to export everything to the live server. Is it possible to use features or just export sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Features module allows you to **export all the configurations in code** (instead of DB). It is very usefull when you have 2 separated versions of database, in example one for your localhost or test installation, and one for your live/production website.

*However, if you want to deploy the local database to the live server too, it is not necessary to export everything with Features.*

Comment: So if live server has clean database and if i export via features, the pages online will show everything similar to localhost pages?

Comment: After re-reading your question, I just want to clarify that it is not possible to export "content" with Features. That means that if you have created a page or a block in your local Drupal, it is not possible to export it in code and deploy it on your live server. If you want to move all the content too, you have to export your local database... Am I clear enough? :P

Comment: oh it means i have to create pages, views and blocks over again on the live one then? Sigh I thought it would help to save time lol

Comment: Yes indeed! But if you have a very clean work on your local DB and if it is the first live deployment of your project, you can import your DB on live server :-)

Comment: Local DB - export all contents right? So what is the point of exporting content when I have to create pages, views and blocks over again :(

Comment: If you export your database in .sql and import it on your live server, you won't have to create all your content over again!

I just wanted to say that Features is not the solution you were looking for. There is no other way (to my knowledge) to export content than by exporting the database in .sql... :-(

Comment: My pleasure ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I love using features for just what you're describing you need. I admit it's a bit challenging at first, and doesn't always appear to work as expected. Here are some videos that I think may be helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P874hgin5xI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHbOh9bf1dg&list=PL-Ve2ZZ1kZNTykHOLO0jzRADq8iZxvzkU (several by Shane Thomas, codekarate)

If you want to export individual content, you have modules such as https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features, but that's not for large scale use. I think you'll want this: https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export. It makes import/export of nodes pretty easy.

Hope this helps some.